# How can I host NextJS on AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

I have created EC2 with MS Windows. I have downloaded and installed NodeJS and:

1. npx create-next-app@latest
2. npm run build
3. npm start

Confirmed that http://localhost:3000 works on the EC2

Set up the IPv4 TCP for port 3000

sgr-07ad45d8794867fac   IPv4    Custom TCP  TCP 3000    0.0.0.0/0   –

http://ec2-3-25-154-60.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000 doesn't work, This site can’t be reached

http://3.25.154.60:3000 doesn't work, This site can’t be reached

I am completely stuck

Comment: You give very little information; but 9 times of 10 it's misconfigured security group. If you are sure about the security group - check Windows firewall

Comment: I am using the security group created when I created the EC2 instance. To this security group I have added: sgr-07ad45d8794867fac IPv4 Custom TCP TCP 3000 0.0.0.0/0

I have also added HTTP IPV4 and HTTPS IPV4

Comment: It was Windows firewall. ALl I had to do was add Incoming rule to allow port 3000, many thanks